# Flex 3 Using an ArrayCollection to Populate Both a Datagrid and a ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, datagrid, combobox, arraycollection

I use this arrayCollection to populate a Flex 3 Datagrid. I'd also like to use this arrayCollection to populate a comboBox with the Name node.

In the arrayCollection, I've got the Name listed twice. I've got two rows in the Datagrid.

If I set the ComboBox's labelfield to Name, then the Name will be listed twice in the ComboBox menu. Is there a way to use this arrayCollection and have each Name listed only once in the comboBox?

I can always make another loop and array collection for the Name, but I was wondering if there were a better way.

```
    var i:uint; 
    for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        myDGArray = [
         {Name: myArray[i].Name, Subject: 'Math:', Pass: myArray[i].math_pass, Fail: myArray[i].math_fail},
         {Name: myArray[i].Name, Subject: 'Reading:', Pass: myArray[i].reading_pass, Fail: myArray[i].reading_fail}
                             ]
                }

myAC=new ArrayCollection(myDGArray);
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused.  Based on your code sample, the name will be listed twice in the ComboBox because the same name is used twice in your dataProvider.

You may want o consider converting your dataProvider to two separate ListCollectionView objects, provide different filtering on each object and use those each as se[separate dataProviders.

In psuedo code this is how I'd do it:

```
public var comboBoxCollection : ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(myAC );
public var dataGridCollection : ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(myAC );
```

The apply filtering on the comboBoxCollection to filter out entries with duplicate names. [More info on collection filtering in the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_4.html).

Comment: Hi, www.Flextras.com,
Thanks so much for the reply. The CollectonView is what I'm looking for. I hadn't hear of it. Thanks for the advice and link.

Comment: ListCollectionView is the parent, if memory serves me, of both ArrayCollection and XMLListCollection.